# how to calculate slop and do operations between multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have this dataframe

```
   Name  Op  A    B    C
   Ob1   L   1    2    3
         F   2    4    6 
   Ob2   L   4    5    6
         F   8    10  12
```

where Name y Op are index and subindex, but I have to do some operation between multiindex rows like, multiply them: `Mult=L*F` and show the answer in a new subindex, I am expecting this:

```
   Name  Op  A    B    C
   Ob1   L   1    2    3
         F   2    4    6 
        Mult 2    8    18
   Ob2   L   4    5    6
         F   8    10   12 
        Mult 32   50   72
```

but I really don't know how to start.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to take some cross sections [`xs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html#pandas-dataframe-xs) to do the operations with:

```
mult_df = df.xs('L', 0, 'Op').mul(df.xs('F', 0, 'Op'))
```

`mult_df`:

```
       A   B   C
Name            
Ob1    2   8  18
Ob2   32  50  72
```

Create an aligning MultiIndex:

```
mult_df['Op'] = 'Mult'
mult_df = mult_df.set_index('Op', append=True)
```

`mult_df`:

```
            A   B   C
Name Op              
Ob1  Mult   2   8  18
Ob2  Mult  32  50  72
```

Then [`append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas-dataframe-append) and [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-index):

```
new_df = df.append(mult_df).sort_index()
```

`new_df`:

```
            A   B   C
Name Op              
Ob1  F      2   4   6
     L      1   2   3
     Mult   2   8  18
Ob2  F      8  10  12
     L      4   5   6
     Mult  32  50  72
```

---

As a one-liner:

```
new_df = df.append(
    df.xs('L', 0, 'Op')
        .mul(df.xs('F', 0, 'Op'))
        .assign(Op='Mult')
        .set_index('Op', append=True)
).sort_index()
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Ob1', 'Ob1', 'Ob2', 'Ob2'],
    'Op': ['L', 'F', 'L', 'F'],
    'A': [1, 2, 4, 8],
    'B': [2, 4, 5, 10],
    'C': [3, 6, 6, 12]
}).set_index(['Name', 'Op'])

new_df = df.append(
    df.xs('L', 0, 'Op')
        .mul(df.xs('F', 0, 'Op'))
        .assign(Op='Mult')
        .set_index('Op', append=True)
).sort_index()

print(new_df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution - a little too late, but It may also come handy.

```
>>> data = [{'Name': 'Ob1', 'Op': 'L', 'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3},
 {'Name': 'Ob1', 'Op': 'F', 'A': 2, 'B': 4, 'C': 6},
 {'Name': 'Ob2', 'Op': 'L', 'A': 4, 'B': 5, 'C': 6},
 {'Name': 'Ob2', 'Op': 'F', 'A': 8, 'B': 10, 'C': 12}]

>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
>>> df_agg = df.groupby('Name').agg('prod').assign(Op='Mult').reset_index()
>>> df.append(df_agg, ignore_index=True).groupby(['Name','Op']).first()


                A   B   C
       Name Op          
        Ob1 F   2   4   6
            L   1   2   3
          Mult  2   8   18
        Ob2 F   8   10  12
            L   4   5   6
         Mult   32  50  72
```